# Calling methods with delays/sleeps in between

Tags: ios, multithreading, ios7, nsobject

I am in the middle of writing a music game for iOS. What I am trying to do is have the computer play a tune, which involves calling a method that plays a sound, pausing, and calling another method that plays a different sound.

So what I am trying to figure out is how to call these methods with delays/sleeps. I have found two ways that are very cumbersome. the first is do use

```
    [self performSelector:@selector(startNotePlay:) withObject:button afterDelay:.5];
    [self performSelector:@selector(startNotePlay:) withObject:button afterDelay:2.5];
    etc etc...
```

However this way is very annoying because all the methods are called at once so the delay has to keep into account how long the pauses are and how long the notes before are playing. so a lot of math would need to be done...

The second way is to use sleep, which is much easier.

```
[self performSelector:@selector(startNotePlay:) withObject:button afterDelay:.5];
sleep(2.0);
[self performSelector:@selector(startNotePlay:) withObject:button afterDelay:1.5];
```

the problem with this is that sleep shuts down the main thread. So I can't do any UI changes while sleep is happening.

Is there anything that is in between these two? Basically is there anyway to perform sleep without shutting down everything. Or something like, perform this method, then perform that method after X delay?

Thanks for the help,
Gabe

Comment: Which API are you using to play the sounds? How do you know how long the sounds are? Can the user pause between the sounds (or do you need to be able to cancel)?

Answer (score 0):

How about performing one selector and then perform the other one INSIDE this one after a delay? that way you know the one is gonna go off after the other one? :)

Otherwise you can maybe execute a method on a certain time using `timeIntervalSinceNow`

Answer (score 0):

Just based on this information, I would suggest running this code on a background thread.  I assume your note playing code is necessarily running on the main thread.  You can, more or less, get the timing you're looking for using something like this.

```
dispatch_queue_t queue = dispatch_queue_create("musicQueue", NULL);
dispatch_async(queue, ^{
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue() ^{
        [self performSelector:@selector(startNotePlay:) withObject:button afterDelay:.5];
    });
});
dispatch_async(queue, ^{
    sleep(2.0f);
});
dispatch_async(queue, ^{
    dispatch_sync(dispatch_get_main_queue() ^{
        [self performSelector:@selector(startNotePlay:) withObject:button afterDelay:1.5];
    });
});
```

There are undoubtedly better ways to accomplish your goal, but without more information, i.e. source code, it's hard to provide a better solution.